# Highlight all words in a line

Tags: font-lock, highlighting

Is there an easy way to highlight all the words in a line with just one command? I'm trying to write an elisp function to achieve this but my knowledge is pretty rudimentary. So far, I can only move the point to the beginning of the line and highlight the word there:

```
(defun hx ()
  "Highlight all words in a line."
  (interactive)
  (beginning-of-line)
  ;; Split string based on comma-separator
  (let ((mylist (split-string (thing-at-point 'line t) ","))))
  
  (highlight-symbol-at-point)

)
```

I was hoping to iterate over `mylist` and use `re-search-forward` to find the first occurrence of each word in the list, move the point to that word and then highlight it. However, `mylist` contains an empty list. Even if `mylist` contained a list of words, I don't know if the above approach would actually work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mylist` is only usable inside the body of `let`. your `(highlight-symbol-at-point)` is not inside of this `let`

Btw. `highlight-symbol-at-point` is just a alias for `hi-lock-face-symbol-at-point` (use `M-.` to get to the source code).

So I took the source code of latter and your code and combined it into a working version:

```
(defun hx ()
  "Highlight all words in a line."
  (interactive)
  (beginning-of-line)
  ;; Split string based on comma-separator
  (let ((mylist (split-string (thing-at-point 'line t) ",")))
    (dolist (item mylist)
      (let ((hi-lock-auto-select-face t)
            (face (hi-lock-read-face-name)))
        (or (facep face) (setq face 'hi-yellow))
        (unless hi-lock-mode (hi-lock-mode 1))
        (hi-lock-set-pattern item face)))))
```

Note, that you are splitting that line at `,`, not `space`.        `(beginning-of-line)` is not needed.

Note, you might need to `(require 'hi-lock)` before using this function.

Note, this function uses (with default Emacs settings) different colors for every (different) string. It is asking which color to use at the minibuffer.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to set a different color for each of the underlying strings in the line? I should've made this explicit in my question.

Comment: It is, using different colors, at least with standard emacs config. It prompts at the minibuffer, which color it should use for which string.